# Crossnetwork messaging on irc using C#

Tags: c#, irc

I am trying to log activity of a certain IRC channel, into another. I can make my program to message the activity, but on the wrong network. The second channel is on a different network, tough i'm connected to both, it takes the message on network A and posts it also on network A, while that should be B

```
static void _irc_IRCMessageReceived(object sender, string message, User user, IRCChannel channel)
{
    if (message.StartsWith("!Op"))
    {       
        _irc.SendMessage(message, channel1);
    }
}
```

Comment: IRCChannel is provided by some library which you haven't mentioned. You should consider explicitly mentioning what library you're using and/or adding a tag.

Comment: I'm using Amrykid.Web.IRC;

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are posting it to the same network you are receiving it from. '_irc' is Network A where you are getting the message from, then you turn around and send it back to the network. You need to keep a reference to the IRCClient class for Network B and send it to that message instead of '_irc' (Network A).

Side-Note: I wrote that IRC library a long time ago when I was inexperienced. I recommend using the IRC component from one of my IRC Bots: http://github.com/Amrykid/Sayuka